# Dynamically create scope variables and ng-models in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using [this](https://github.com/fraserxu/ionic-rating) angular directive to add rating to my Ionic app.

Including two ratings on one page would look like this:

```
$scope.rating1 = {};
$scope.rating1.rate = 0;
$scope.rating1.max = 5;

$scope.rating2 = {};
$scope.rating2.rate = 0;
$scope.rating2.max = 5;

<rating ng-model="rating1.rate" max="rating1.max"></rating>
<rating ng-model="rating2.rate" max="rating2.max"></rating>
```

This works well, but I wish to integrate this in an ng-repeat which shows a certain amount of questions.

Something like:

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="n in notif">{{n.question}}<br />
<rating ng-model="rating{{n.id}}.rate" max="rating{{n.id}}.max">
</rating>
</ion-list>
```

but that doesn't work.

I'm also wondering how I could "make" the scope vars depending on the amount of question. Right now, I just added

```
$scope.rating1 = {};
$scope.rating1.rate = 0;
$scope.rating1.max = 5;

$scope.rating2 = {};
$scope.rating2.rate = 0;
$scope.rating2.max = 5;

...
```

ten times, but can this be dynamic too in Angular?

**Update:**

I've managed to make the scopes and give them a value using:

```
        function make_rating_scopes(string, value)
        {
            var the_string = string;
            var model = $parse(the_string);
            model.assign($scope, value);
            $scope.$apply();
        }
```

but the first part is still a mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-thinking this.  Rating can be any object (`{}`).  Since your `notif` is an array of `question` objects, you can simply add a property to represent the rating.  You can also add a property for the `max`, or use a `$scope` property if all the `max` are the same.

For example:

```js
$scope.maxRating = 10;
$scope.notif = [{
  question: "question1",
  rating: 3
}, {
  question: "question2",
  rating: 4
}, {
  question: "question3",
  rating: 5
}, {
  question: "question4",
  rating: 8
}];
```

```html
<ion-list ng-repeat="n in notif">
  {{n.question}}
  <rating ng-model="n.rating" max="maxRating"></rating>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Nice, that seems to work! Any idea how I can get the value of a rating? I used to use `$scope.rating.rate` ...

Comment: you still are overthinking this.  the `rating1`, `rating2`, etc. objects aren't necessary for this component.  It merely takes a value that is assignable and a max and produces the display element.  In case of my example, `n.rating` (or `$scope.notif[0].rating`, `$scope.notif[1].rating`, etc.) hold the value that changes and is reflected in the display.  these could just as easily be `$scope.notif[0].rate` or `$scope.notif[0].someCrazyNameForRatingVariable`.  The rating is simply a property of the object, nothing more.